# Android use AsyncTask on GridView.setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask

i try to use AsyncTask on GridView.setOnItemClickListener like this :

```
gv_name = (CustomGridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridViewName);

    gv_name .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            new AsyncTaskName().execute();

        }
    });
```

this is AsynncTask :

```
class AsyncTaskName extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, BinderDataName> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected BinderDataName doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(xml_file);
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            http.setDoInput(true);
            http.connect();
            InputStream in = http.getInputStream();
            XmlPullParserName parser_Name = new XmlPullParserName();
            nameList = parser_Name.parse(in, emp_name);
            BinderDataName bd_Name = new BinderDataName(getActivity(), nameHashmap);
            return bd_Name;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(BinderDataName bd_Name) {
        if (bd_Name != null) {
            gv_detail.setAdapter(bd_Name);
        }

    }

}
```

AsyncTask can't execute in GridView.setOnItemClickListener.
if I use it outside GridView.setOnItemClickListener, I can use it.
how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you share your code for AsyncTaskName? Do you have error logs that you can share? Also, does your code have a misspelling in it? You are instantiating a variable `gv_name` as the GridView but setting the listener on `name`

Comment: I was update in my post.

Comment: @Atya Vyas - Lakhan : no, I can't find solution